# PowerShell script to send me email alerts of Event Viewer errors/warnings/failures

Tags: powershell, email, server, event-viewer

I am trying to edit the script below to utilize the task scheduler send me an email notification every time an error/warning/failure is logged in our servers Event Viewer.

Important info:

- I am brand new to PowerShell
- The from email and to email are both apart of my company's outlook exchange server
- I need this script to pull events from the "Windows" log folder in Event Viewer
- I also believe this script requires a module installation, which I am struggling to figure out how to do
- I need to know what to edit (I believe in the parameters) to make to fit my specific use case

Thanks in advance for any help at all. Here is the script from https://github.com/blachniet/blachniet-psutils/blob/master/Send-EventEntryEmail.psm1 :

```
Import-Module $PSScriptRoot\Send-EventEntryEmail.psm1

Function Send-EventEntryEmail {

[CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter()]
        [string] $LogName = "System""Application""Security,
    
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string] $Source,
    
        [Parameter()]
        [int] $Newest = 5,

        [Parameter()]
        [string[]] $EntryType = "Error""Warning""Failure",
    
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string] $SmtpUser = "helpdesk@mydomain.com",
    
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string] $SmtpPassword = "passwordexample",
    
        [Parameter()]
        [int] $SmtpPort = 587,
    
        [Parameter()]
        [string] $SmtpServer = "smtp.mail.outlook.com",
    
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string] $MailFrom = "helpdesk@mydomain.com",
    
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string] $MailTo = "myemail@mydomain.com,
    
        [Parameter()]
        [string] $Subject = "EventLogAlert",

    )

    # Get the event entries.
    $eventEntries = Get-EventLog -LogName $LogName -Source $Source -Newest $Newest -EntryType $EntryType

    # Create a table row for each entry.
    $rows = ""
    foreach ($eventEntry in $eventEntries){
        $rows += @"
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center; padding: 5px;">$($eventEntry.TimeGenerated)</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; padding: 5px;">$($eventEntry.EntryType)</td>
            <td style="padding: 5px;">$($eventEntry.Message)</td>
        </tr>
"@
    }

    # Create the email.
    $email = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage( $MailFrom , $MailTo )
    $email.Subject = $Subject
    $email.IsBodyHtml = $true
    $email.Body = @"
    <table style="width:100%;border">
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align: center; padding: 5px;">Time</th>
            <th style="text-align: center; padding: 5px;">Type</th>
            <th style="text-align: center; padding: 5px;">Message</th>
        </tr>
    
    $rows
    </table>
"@

    # Send the email.
    $SMTPClient=New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient( $SmtpServer , $SmtpPort )
    $SMTPClient.EnableSsl=$true
    $SMTPClient.Credentials=New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential( $SmtpUser , $SmtpPassword );
    $SMTPClient.Send( $email )
}

Export-ModuleMember Send-EventEntryEmail
```

Below are the errors I get in ISE when I run this current script:

```
At line:17 char:34
+         [string[]] $EntryType = "Error""Warning""Failure",
+                                  ~
Missing ')' in function parameter list.
At line:35 char:49
+         [string] $MailTo = "myemail@mydomain.com,
+                                                 ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
At line:37 char:20
+         [Parameter()]
+                    ~
An expression was expected after '('.
At line:38 char:45
+         [string] $Subject = "EventLogAlert",
+                                             ~
Missing expression after ','.
At line:3 char:31
+ Function Send-EventEntryEmail {
+                               ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
At line:40 char:5
+     )
+     ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
At line:78 char:1
+ }
+ ~
Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndParenthesisInFunctionParameterList
```

Comment: There is no need to install the module. Put this script next to your main .ps1 script. In your main script write: `Import-Module $PSScriptRoot\Send-EventEntryEmail.psm1`. Call the function `Send-EventEntryEmail`. If you still have problems with this, edit your question to show how you call the function.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much for the quick reply. So based on your response I am assuming that I would put Import-Module $PSScriptRoot\Send-EventEntryEmail.psm1 the very beginning... then the line of Function Send-EventEntryEmail{ would call the function?

Comment: Yes. You call the function like so: `Send-EventEntryEmail -Source Application -SmtpUser ...`. You need to pass all parameters that have attribute `Mandatory=$true` in the source file.

Comment: Task scheduler will pass the ID of the triggering event. That lets you avoid sending a table of events (since you will get emailed each time the event occurs).

Comment: @Mitch That would only cover a single ID though, correct? My goal is to have this email me every time any warning/error/failure is logged in Event Viewer, not a specific ID

Comment: @sls1993, no.  This refers to the `EventRecordID` - which refers to an individual logged event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subscribe to Event Log via email by setting a scheduled task which will receive the notice of a new event and deliver it by email.

From the Task Scheduler, you start by adding a task triggered by "On an event".  To subscribe to a particular Log/Source/Event ID combination, use "Basic".  To subscribe to many events, use "Custom" with an event filter meeting your needs.

[image: Event trigger]

Either way, the second step is a powershell script which can inspect the event and forward it by email.  This can be done by adding an action in Task Scheduler which calls `powershell.exe` and passes the agruments `.\MyDelightfulScriptName.ps1 -eventRecordID $(eventRecordID) -eventChannel $(eventChannel)`.

[image: Trigger]

Then follow [bergerb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71006187/138200)'s instructions to pass the event record ID and channel to powershell.

To access the event that was logged, the powershell script uses `Get-WinEvent` with the `EventRecordID` filter:

```
# Collects all named paramters (all others end up in $Args)
param($eventRecordID,$eventChannel)

$event = Get-WinEvent -LogName $eventChannel -FilterXPath "<QueryList><Query Id='0' Path='$eventChannel'><Select Path='$eventChannel'>*[System[(EventRecordID=$eventRecordID)]]</Select></Query></QueryList>";

Send-MailMessage `
    -From 'evetlog@server.domain.local' `
    -To 'admin@domain.local' `
    -Subject ($event.Message.Split([Environment]::NewLine)[0]) `
    -SmtpServer 'smtp.domain.local' `
    -Body ($event.Message);
```

Comment: Okay thank you this helps tremendously. One question, when creating the Action... wouldn't I need to direct the action to the specific script.ps1 file rather than powershell.exe, or does the argument below do that. If the latter, would the "Start in:" need to be the location in which my powershell script is stored?

Comment: Since powershell is interpreted rather than compiled, it is usually required to put `powershell` as the program, and put the path to the script in the arguments field. I know Powershell support has been improving with each w10 release, so it may no longer be necessary. The start in field should be the folder which contains the ps1 file.

Comment: Thank you Mitch, the task is now running in task scheduler and shows that it is completing successfully; however, I am not receiving any email alerts. Would this indicate that I am likely using the wrong address in the SMTP server portion of the script you provided?

Comment: Not sure. You might use wireshark to see what is happening with smtp. A capture filter of “port 25” should work. You can trigger your task using the powershell command `Write-EventLog`

Answer (score 3):

Very important Info missing: You need to adjust the XML of your task (add `ValueQueries`), after you created the Trigger!

(Export, adjust, Import)

```
<EventTrigger>
  <Enabled>true</Enabled>
  <Subscription> ... </Subscription>
  <ValueQueries>
    <Value name="eventRecordID">Event/System/EventRecordID</Value>
    <Value name="eventChannel">Event/System/Channel</Value>
  </ValueQueries>
</EventTrigger>
```

Nice-to-read:
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/archive/blogs/wincat/trigger-a-powershell-script-from-a-windows-event

I also adjusted the script to allow for Authentication, adjusted it to UTF-8 so äöü will work and added some more Information to the subject:

```
# Collects all named paramters (all others end up in $Args)
param($eventRecordID,$eventChannel)

$event = Get-WinEvent -LogName $eventChannel -FilterXPath "<QueryList><Query Id='0' Path='$eventChannel'><Select Path='$eventChannel'>*[System[(EventRecordID=$eventRecordID)]]</Select></Query></QueryList>";

# Plaintext-Password
#$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "<password>" -AsPlainText -Force

# To generate the Secure-String, run the following command, and paste your secure-string below
#ConvertTo-SecureString "<password>" -AsPlainText -Force | ConvertFrom-SecureString
$secpasswd = "<secure-string>" | ConvertTo-SecureString

$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("<username>", $secpasswd)

# Maybe you need to set your SecurityProtocol
#[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

Send-MailMessage `
    -From '<sender>' `
    -To '<receiver>' `
    -Subject "$env:COMPUTERNAME EVENTLOG $($event.Message.Split([Environment]::NewLine)[0][0..30] -join '')" `
    -SmtpServer '<server>' `
    -Credential $cred `
    -Body ($event.Message) `
    -Port 587 `
    -UseSsl `
    -Encoding UTF8;
```